# Batch File That Keeps Both Files When a Name Conflict Occurs and renames file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to creating .bat files. I am trying to create a batch file that will move or copy file(s) from one directory to another, and if the file(s) exists in the destination directory it will rename the file with a (1). Below is what I have for a .bat file to copy but it overwrites the file in the destination directory.

```
    copy /-y "C:\Users\Private\Desktop\Move-Copy\1\1.txt" "C:\Users\Private\Desktop\Move-Copy\2"
    pause
```

Comment: There is no single command that will do what you're asking. It's functionality that Explorer adds. If you want to implement the same thing, you'll have to use `if exist` and some looping code yourself to figure out if one (or more) copies of the file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

The following script provides a sub-routine `:SUB_COPY`, which can do what you want, namely copying files without overwriting already existing ones but generating new unique names in case. The routine expects two command line arguments: the first one is the path to the source item(s) (wildcards `?` and `*` are supported; a directory is allowed too), the second one is the path to the target (destination) directory. So here is the script:

```dos
@echo off
call :SUB_COPY "C:\Users\Private\Desktop\Move-Copy\1\1.txt" "TARGET=C:\Users\Private\Desktop\Move-Copy\2"
exit /B


:SUB_COPY source_item target_dir
if not "%~3"=="" (
    >&2 echo ERROR: too many arguments!
)
set "SOURCE=%~f1"
if not defined SOURCE (
    >&2 echo ERROR: missing argument!
    exit /B 1
) else if not exist "%SOURCE%" (
    >&2 echo ERROR: source not found!
    exit /B 1
)
set "TARGET=%~f2"
if not defined TARGET set "TARGET=."

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
    2^> nul xcopy /L /Y /I "%SOURCE%" "%TEMP%\" ^| findstr /V /R "^[0-9]"
') do (
    call :SUB_DO "%%~I" "%TARGET%"
)
exit /B

:SUB_DO source_file target_dir
set "SUFFIX="
:CHECK
if exist "%~f2\%~n1%SUFFIX%%~x1" (
    set /A SUFFIX-=1
) else (
    2> nul md "%~f2"
    > nul 2>&1 copy /B "%~f1" "%~f2\%~n1%SUFFIX%%~x1" && (
        echo INFO: copied "%~nx1" as "%~n1%SUFFIX%%~x1".
    ) || (
        >&2 echo ERROR: copying of "%~nx1" failed!
        exit /B 1
    )
    exit /B
)
goto :CHECK
```

Firstly, the sub-routine `:SUB_COPY` checks the provided arguments for validity. Afterwards there is a `for /F` loop which enumerates the source items, so to resolve directories and wildcards `?` and `*` in case (this loop parses the output of `xcopy /L`, just to resolve the source and return individual files (non-recursively); `/L` tells to not copy anything but list the files only). Inside of this loop, another sub-routine `:SUB_DO` is called, which does the copying of a single file; this routine checks whether a file with the same name exists in the target directory, and if so, a suffix `-1` is appended to the file name; the check is repeated then, and if still a file is found, the suffix becomes `-2`, and so on, until a new file name is found, which does not occur in the target directory, and so the copying is actually performed.

Comment: How can I use this to recursively go through a bunch of subfolders and move the files into the parent folder?

Comment: What do you mean by "parent folder" in that situation? do you want to move the files one directory level up, or do you want to move them into the common root directory which you want to search recursively?

Comment: Yes, common root directory that i am searching recursively i used this ... for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a:-D /s /b') do move "%%f" . but move will overwrite the file

Comment: Ok I managed to do ... for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a:-D /s /b') do call :SUB_COPY "%%f" "I:\" .... however the for loop is also loop the files directly in I:/

Comment: Hmm... this would be worth a new question, wouldn't it? Anyway... At first I would append the root directory `I:\` to the `dir` command line (so you get `dir /a:-D /s /b "I:\"`); then you could put `if /I not "%%~dpf"=="I:\" ` in front of the `call` command line in order to exclude all the files in the root; finally replace `copy /B` by `move`...

Comment: ...of course you need to adapt the `call` command line as well (sorry, but I forgot that before): `call :SUB_COPY "%%~ff" "I:\"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112212/discussion-between-elgabbu-and-aschipfl).