# I want to create "New folder" using Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to create "New folder" in desktop and "New folder (2)" if "New folder" already exists.But I end with two folders every time. I want to check Condition or while loop whatever you suggest to make it happen.

```
mkdir C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\"New folder"
if exist C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\"New folder" mkdir C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\"New folder (2)"
```

Comment: Do not quote parts of a path, always quote the whole paths, like: `mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder"`. Note that the root path of the conditional `mkdir` command is different to the others. `if exist` checks for files *and* folders, unless you append a `\ `to the checked path to check folders only...

Comment: If you `mkdir "New Folder"` first, it will always exist, and therefore your second call will always execute and create "New Folder (2)". Read the code you've written. It says *Make the directory "New Folder". Now if it exists, make the directory "New Folder (2)"*. It will **always** exist, because you've just created it yourself. You need to test for the existence of "New Folder" **first** instead of just calling `mkdir` to create it.

Comment: @aschipfl Thx for the input of always quote the whole path.
Edit: Yes, I tried with both if exist and if not exist

Comment: @ken yes, that's what i'm concerning too. I want to check the condition If new folder exists create new folder 2,but it takes it as make both folder. What should I change ?

Comment: Yokesh, I've already told you what to fix, in my first comment. Read the last sentence. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses a counter and creates a new folder every time it runs (`new folder`, `new folder (1)`, `new folder (2)`...)

```
@echo off
set  counter=0
mkdir "new folder" 2>nul || goto :TryNext
:continue
REM rest of your code

goto :eof
:TryNext
set /a counter+=1
mkdir "new folder (%counter%)" 2>nul || goto :TryNext
goto :continue
```

`||` acts as "if mkdir failed *) then"
`2>nul` suppresses the errormessage ("subdirectory already exists")

*) because the folder does already exist

Comment: Jus one more. I don't want to create new folder(1) alone
Should go like this, new folder, new folder(2), new folder(3), new folder(4)... What should i do??

Comment: just change the startcounter from `set counter=0` to `set counter=1`

Comment: That does it. You did fine coding. Thanks @stephan.

Answer (score 0):

You end up with two folders every time because your first statement is not conditional. This means that there will always be a "New folder" created, no matter what the circumstance. Your first conditional statement checks for the existence of that folder, which will always be created on the first line and therefore the condition will always be true... creating "New folder (2)" every time the script is run.

Comment: What should I include to check the condition ?

Comment: @YokeshKdk you should check if "New folder" does not exist, like so:

    if not exist "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder" mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder"

Comment: @YokeshKdk **CORRECTION:** if not exist "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder" exit 0

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if exist "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder" (
    mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder (2)"
) else (
    mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder"
)
```

instead.

In your code you check if it exists at the second line but it will always exist because your first line will create the "New folder" wether it already exists or not. So both directories are always created

Comment: That's a typo. Edited.
Your code should work by logic, but still it is not working. does it creates folders in your side?

Comment: I corrected my answer following the correction of your typo. Yes it did work on my side

Answer (score 0):

```
if exist C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\"New folder" mkdir C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\"New folder (2)"
mkdir C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\"New folder"
```

would seem to be the obvious solution - quote-positioning being another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. You are creating a directory, then you are checking whether it exists; unless there are no restrictions in creating directories, the check will always succeed, of course.

To achieve your goal, you need to check for existence in advance:

```dos
rem // Check for existance of first directory:
if exist "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder\" (
    rem // First directory exists, so create second one:
    mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder (2)"
) else (
    rem // First directory does not exist, so create it:
    mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder"
)
```

Or:

```dos
rem // Check for existance of first directory; if exists, create second one:
if exist "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder\" mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder (2)"
rem // Create first directory, suppress error message in case it already exists:
mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder" 2> nul
```

I appended a trailing `\` to the path at `if exist` in order to check for an existing directory; without it, `if exist` checks for both, existing files *and*  directories.

I also assumed that your second directory should be at the same location as the first one (you stated `C:\Users\K YOKESH\Desktop`, which I assumed it should read `C:\Users\kdk\Desktop`).

---

Concerning quotation: you should always enclose the whole path within `""`, not only single path elements -- see above how I did it.

---

Just a hint: to avoid stating the same paths multiple times, you could use environment variables:

```dos
rem // Define paths here:
set "FirstDir=C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder"
set "SecondDir=C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder (2)"

rem // Check for existance of first directory:
if exist "%FirstDir\" (
    rem // First directory exists, so create second one:
    mkdir "%SecondDir%"
) else (
    rem // First directory does not exist, so create it:
    mkdir "%FirstDir%"
)
```

Or:

```dos
rem // Define paths here:
set "FirstDir=C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder"
set "SecondDir=C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder (2)"

rem // Check for existance of first directory; if exists, create second one:
if exist "%FirstDir%\" mkdir "%SecondDir%"
rem // Create first directory, suppress error message in case it already exists:
mkdir "%FirstDir%" 2> nul
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This code does the trick

    if exist "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder" mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder (2)"
    else 
    {
    mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder"
    }

Comment: Jus one more, I tried to create new folder 3 with same method 
Checking for " if new folder and new folder 2 already exists create new folder 3. But that jus doesn't work. How would you do it?

Comment: `if exist "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder" mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder (2)" else { mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder" }` cannot work, because you need parentheses around the first `mkdir` and braces are not understood, it should read: `if exist "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder" (mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder (2)") else (mkdir "C:\Users\kdk\Desktop\New folder")` (the parentheses around the second `mkdir` may be omitted)...

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36992624) -- this is not for creating folders but files, using suffixes `-1`, `-2`, etc., in case they already exist; this could be adapted to cover creation of folders instead...